# Run Class methods in threads (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, class, methods

I'm currently learning Python and Classes and I have a basic question, but I didn't find any answer to it. Let's say I have this dummy class

```
class DomainOperations:
    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.domain = domain
        self.domain_ip = ''
        self.website_thumbnail = ''

    def resolve_domain(self):
        #resolve domain to ipv4 and save to self.domain_ip

    def generate_website_thumbnail(self):
        #generate website thumbnail and save the url to self.website_thumbnail
```

I want to run simultaneously resolve_domain and generate_website_thumbnail and when the threads are finished I want to print the IP and the thumbnail.

**EDIT:** I know I should use threads, maybe something like this

```
r = DomainOperations('google.com')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=r.resolve_domain)
t1.start()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=r.generate_website_thumbnail)
t2.start()
```

But should I use them outside the Class? Should I write another Class to handle Threads?

What is the **right way** to do that?

Comment: Wonder whether it will work if you construct the threads additionally with `args=(r,)`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you call them from the class, it is as simple as:

```
import threading

class DomainOperations:

    def __init__(self):
        self.domain_ip = ''
        self.website_thumbnail = ''

    def resolve_domain(self):
        self.domain_ip = 'foo'

    def generate_website_thumbnail(self):
        self.website_thumbnail= 'bar'

    def run(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.resolve_domain)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.generate_website_thumbnail)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        print(self.domain_ip, self.website_thumbnail)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = DomainOperations()
    d.run()
```

Comment: huh. I couldn't get this to work in my code today, so I had to take my method out of the class and pass the object as a parameter. I apologize.

Comment: @A.Rodas pastebin is not available anymore. any way to get the example in another way? thanks

Comment: @SergioMorstabilini I've updated the snippet, hope it helps!

Comment: To clarify: is it also possible to call twice the same method from separate thread?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli Yes, but if you call it at the same time a race condicion might occur.

Comment: @jasondancks I am having a similar problem to what you firstly described, and having the method as `@staticmethod` and passing `self` as a regular arguent solves it. Did you realize the root of this behavior?

Comment: @jasondancks you could also pass self as an argument and call the class' method: `my_thread = threading.Thread(target=ClassName.class_thread_method, args = (self,) )`

Comment: @jasondancks Would you like to remove your first (and maybe follow-up) comment?  I know it was a long time ago... but I was a bit startled to read your comment when I found this helpful answer today!

Comment: now it's 2022and your method is working

Answer (score 8):

You can inherit Thread class in DomainOperation, in this way code would be more clean and easily understandable. you have to override a *run()* method.

```
from threading import Thread

class DomainOperations(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.domain_ip = ''
       self.website_thumbnail = ''

   def resolve_domain(self):
       self.domain_ip = 'foo'

   def generate_website_thumbnail(self):
       self.website_thumbnail= 'bar'

   def run(self):
       #domain will be resolved on first thread
       self.resolve_domain()
       #thumbnail will be resolved on second OR newly created below thread
       thread2 = Thread(target=self.generate_website_thumbnail)
       thread.start()
       # thread1 will wait for thread2
       self.join()
       # thread2 will wait for thread1, if it's late.
       thread2.join()
       # here it will print ip and thumbnail before exiting first thread
       print(self.domain_ip, self.website_thumbnail)
```

And you will start your threads in this way.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   thread1 = DomainOperations()
   thread1.start()
```

Comment: This will error with RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called, you need to add super(DomainOperations, self).__init__(self) to __init__

Answer (score -9):

```
def post_test(tbid, line_num, response_time):
    """
    :param tbid: 参数id
    :return:
    """

    # 请求参数
    data = {'tbId': tbid, 'conditions': [{"key": "", "type": 1}], 'pageNum': 1, 'pageSize': 12}
    # 请求启动时间

    start = time.time()
    # post请求
    r = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    # 请求结束时间
    end = time.time()
    # 保留两位小数
    finall_time = float('%.2f' % float(end - start))
    text = json.loads(r.text)
    # IO写入 只写入200的
    with open('text6.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
       if text['statusCode'] == '200':
        throughput = line_num * response_time / finall_time
        throughput = float('%.2f' % float(throughput))
        print('the perf_counter time of %s is %s and the content is %s ,throughput is %s' % (
            tbid, finall_time, json.loads(r.text), throughput))
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        spamwriter.writerow([tbid] + [finall_time] + [throughput])
def start_thread(csv_name):
  tbid, response_time_sort, throughput_sort = read_csv(csv_name)
  print(tbid)
  line_num = len(tbid)
  response_times = 5

  for j in range(response_times):
    for i in tbid:
        t = threading.Thread(target=post_test, args=(i, line_num, response_times))
        t.start()
        t.join()
```

I don't know how to call a method in a class, especially if it has initialization parameters, but you can try this method。 I'm trying to use multiple processes to solve this problem, right。

Comment: Please translate the chinese comments