# How to run class in separated thread Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes in Python script. One of is `Main()` and the second is `Loading()`

```
class Main:
   pass

class Loading:
   pass
```

At first, works `Main()` that return was filled dictionary

Then is created instance of `Loading()` that iterates all images and downloads them:

```
## LOAD IMAGES ##
imageLoader = Loading()
imageLoader.save()
```

So, the problem is when I call this script it creates one major thread that is waiting for the end of `imageLoader = Loading()`.

As a result, a major thread works so long, it invokes 502 Server error.

How to run `imageLoader = Loading()` in a separate background thread that to release major thread?

What will be launched first in this code:

```
LOADED_IMAGES = {}
IMAGES_ERRORS = []
IMAGES = {"A": "https://images.aif.ru/009/299/3378e1a1ab2d1c6e6be6d38253dd3632.jpg", "B": "http://static1.repo.aif.ru/1/77/623957/b99ee5f894f38261e4d3778350ffbaae.jpg"}

    excel = Excel()
    excel.readExcel(file_path, 'Main')

    imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    Thread(target=imageLoader.run().save()).start()

Does it work line by line or Thread will be created immediately?


**This is full code:**

    class ImageLoader:
        def run(self):
            for article, image in IMAGES.items():
                if image is None or image == '':
                    continue
                LOADED_IMAGES[article] = self.loadImage(self.replaceHttpsProtocol(image), '/home/o/oliwin4/jara/public_html/image/catalog/s/')

        def replaceHttpsProtocol(self, url):
            return url.replace("https:", "http:")

        def nameNameGenerate(self):
            return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        def extention(self, path):
            ext = path.split(".")[-1]
            return '.' + ext if ext else "jpg"

        def save(self):
            for article, image in LOADED_IMAGES.items():
                self.add(article, image)

        def add(self, article, image):
            Products.update(image=image).where(Products.sku == article).execute()

        def loadImage(self, path, path_folder):
            try:

                filename = str(self.nameNameGenerate()) + str(self.extention(path))
                wget.download(url=path, out=path_folder + filename)
                return 'catalog/s/' + filename

            except BaseException as e:
                IMAGES_ERRORS.append(str(e))
```

**Using:**

```
def runOnThread():
    imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    imageLoader.run()
    imageLoader.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     Thread(target=runOnThread, daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: After you used the threaded code, what is the error you getting?

Comment: Also in your code you have this piece of code above your class definition, isn't that making the code run twice? "    imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    Thread(target=imageLoader.run().save()).start()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for which line is blocking your code to run it in a separated thread, usually the blocking line is some kind of I/O or expensive computation.

To do it you can use the threading module.

So, assuming that your blocking line is the

```
imageLoader.save()
```

Try to run it in a separated thread with this code.

```
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=imageLoader.save()).start()
```

Comment: How to put this to `Thread`? `imageLoader = Loading()` and then call `imageLoader.save()`?

Comment: I don't know the insides of your Loading() class, does it get blocked only on the line imageLoader.save()? If so, you can use Thread(target=imageLoader.save()).start(). It will run this line in another thread.

Comment: Be careful, because this will run separately, so if you wan't to do something after this thread finish its job, you need to wait for it to finish. To do that you use the method join(). (ex.: t1 = Thread(target=some_function()).start() and them t1.join() -> this wait the thread to finish. So usually you start a bunch of threads and them wait them all to finish to do some work.

Comment: Can you modify your answer for my case?

Comment: OK, I did it :)

Comment: Yes it is. You can use it without downloading anything.

Comment: I dont see where you create instance `imageLoader()`?

Comment: You can create it just before you run the thread. It is ok. Instance it normally. imageLoader = Loading()

Comment: Move to chat please

Comment: Is it possible to run like this: `Thread(target=imageLoader.run().save()).start()`?

Comment: I mean first method from class then second `save()`?

Comment: Also, will be it run after finished `Main()`?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing your code. I don't know what is blocking you, if it's when you instantiate your Loading class, or when you run the method "save".

Comment: Look this example from stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365406/run-class-methods-in-threads-python

Comment: Try to do it as a function. create a new function which instantiate Loading and them save. And use this function as a target to thread, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use Python's `threading` module for this. Though, a thread takes a reference to a function (passing `target` a function call is useless / wrong).

In your case, if you want to both instantiate then run a function on an object in a separate thread, you should put these two in a function:

```
def runOnThread():
    imageLoader = Loading()
    imageLoader.save()
```

Then pass a reference of this function to a new thread, like so (notice no `()`):

```
from threading import Thread
Thread(target=runOnThread).start()
```

If you don't want the main thread to wait for the new thread to finish, you could make it a [Daemon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) thread, like so:

```
Thread(target=runOnThread, daemon=True).start()
```

---

Shorter version of all the above:

```
from threading import Thread
Thread(target=lambda: Loading().save(), daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: I get twice call of ` Loading()` I dont know why

Comment: @Amely show the code you've just tested (on pastebin or something)

Comment: Does not work, it call twice `run()` also it falls in second iteration in loop: `for article, image in IMAGES.items():`

Comment: I think problem is in `wget.download` it calls exception and thread is falled

Comment: this will deferentially only call whatever function you pass it once, your loop might be iterating twice. Anyway, that's out of your original question.