# Python: run a class method that takes an argument in a new thread

Tags: python-multithreading

I am trying to do the same thing as in this question: [Run Class methods in threads (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365406/run-class-methods-in-threads-python/53288373#53288373), but the class method I want to invoke in a separate thread takes an extra argument, apart from self. A.Rodas's solution does not work: if I try Thread(target=self.class_method, args=(self, arg2)).start(), it says I have 3 arguments instead of 2, while if try args=(arg2), it is breaking my arg2 string into constituent elements and saying 334234 arguments! Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Found the solution! Turns out it wasn't the class method that was causing the error, but the fact that I was sending a tuple of one arg. So I needed to sent args=(arg2,). Note the comma! Got the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116721/python-typeerror-in-threading-function-takes-x-positional-argument-but-y-were

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.class_method, args=(arg2,)).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from the format of your question, but I think the issue is that you shouldn't be including `self` in the `args` tuple.

i.e.

```
threading.Thread(target=self.class_method, args=(arg2)).start()
```